# Xcode UIWebView not showing content of URL, blank white webview, no errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I've been stuck on this for a few days. I am testing this using the iOS Simulator. I have a webView that's suppose to load an URL. It appears to try to load the URL because when I load a Yahoo URL, the Yahoo icon/banner at the top would show, but the actual content of the url would not load, it would just be a blank white space. If I load another URL like "http://www.google.com" that doesn't have any banners on top, it would just be a blank white  webView. If I change the code to open the same URL with the Safari app in the simulator, then everything loads fine. PLEASE HELP!!

WebViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlBusinessLink;

@end
```

WebViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     @try {           
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.urlBusinessLink]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       [self.webView loadRequest: request];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Website is unavailable." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

When I run the code through, there aren't any errors. The exception handling I put in also did not catch anything. It looks like it's either frozen at the very beginning of loading the url, or it is constantly refreshing so none of the content actually shows.

Comment: Hi, which Yahoo URL do you use?

Comment: https://local.yahoo.com/info-21329298-akiko-s-sushi-bar-san-francisco

Comment: For a split second I could see the pictures loading in from yahoo, but I'm talking like a millisecond. Then it disappears and only the yahoo banner shows.

Comment: Your code (without the try-catch block) works fine of me. Is urlBusinessLink a string (if so, you don't need to use stringWithFormat)?

Comment: well I don't think there's anything wrong with the code. Because the webView was showing the URL in an earlier version of my app. Then suddenly it just wouldn't work. It's like it's trying to load into the webpage but either freezes at the very beginning or keeps refreshing the page?

Comment: I am not sure it is correct answer. Bit i had the same problem. After that I changed the url like as http to https. Then it was worked.

Comment: hmm I added a button that manually requests for "https://www.google.com" but not working. blank webview

Comment: I think you should check if the WebView is added to the view, or if the WebView's frame is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use @try @catch blocks.

Use UIWebViewDelegate instead to catch errors

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
....

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

If you loaded View from xib file, use `awakeFromNib` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: added this but still doesn't catch anything

Comment: Where and when you create UIWebView ? Maybe it's just null

Comment: It's create in the storyboard so I'm guessing it creates itself as soon as the view controller loads

Comment: Actually that's true, but in this case use: awakeFromNib instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: can't use that, the previous view allows the user to choose a website to go to and passes that URL to the webviewcontroller. If I use awakeFromNib, the url would be null.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `self.webView.delegate = self`.

And make sure you have added "**UIWebViewDelegate**"

Use the delegate method to identify the loaded URL 
`- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`

Make sure the correct URL got loaded.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thanks. I added it and it go rid of a weird warning I was getting, but the problem still persist.

Comment: Tried the URL "https://local.yahoo.com/info-21329298-akiko-s-sushi-bar-san-francisco" its working fine for me.
Properties I have set:
 NSURLRequest *_urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://local.yahoo.com/info-21329298-akiko-s-sushi-bar-san-francisco"]];


    [notificationWebView loadRequest:_urlReq];
    notificationWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    notificationWebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    [notificationWebView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
This might help!!